# Get input file data from server side in POST method

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I have an input type="file" on my Website I created with NodeJS and Express.
Here is my code as a pug file.

```
form(method='post' action='upload/trainingsdaten')
   form-group
      label.(for='trainingdata') Load Trainingdata
      div
      input#trainingdataInput.(type='file' name="trainingdata" accept=".json, .geojson, .gpkg")
   button#uploadTrainingdata.(type='submit') Upload
```

Now I want to upload the geojson to MongoDB, when the user clicks the Upload Button. So I have to define a POST method on my server side JS file like so right?

```
router.post("/trainingdata", function (req, res, next) {
  
});
```

But how do i access the geojson file in this method?

I also have a client side JS method, which is called, when something is uploaded via the input. There I tried to save the file in the properties of the input. But then I couldn´t access the file either.

```
function fileChange(event) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event) => {

  };
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
  dataTransfer.items.add(event.target.files[0]);
  trainingdataInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
}
```

So as mentioned above my question is:
How do I access the geojson file in my server side JS? Later I have to do the same with a geotiff file, so I can´t pass the data via a String. And I know that I can access data from my form via req.body but the file data I can´t access with this.

Answer (score 1):

With the use of the npm package [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) you can process files in the POST method on the server-side.

After defining the memoryStorage (either in-memory or disk-storage) you can then have single or multiple files processed in one method

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

**Single Upload:**

```
router.post('/trainingdata', upload.single('file'), async(req, res) => {
    let file = req.file;
    await upload(file);
    res.render('filesUploaded');
});
```

**Multiple-File Upload:**

```
router.post('/trainingdata', upload.array('file'), async(req, res) => {
    for (const file of req.files) {
        await upload(file);
    }
    res.render('filesUploaded');
});
```

**On the client side you then just use a form to upload the file:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/trainingdata">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" multiple="true" name="file" />
      <input class="mt-3 form-control btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```